# I lost all bookmark after login chrome on another computer

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

I have many bookmark on one computer and keep google accoutn login and sync.

on another computer, there is only one bookmark, and after I login with same accoutn and sync, all bookmark on computer 1 is overwritten by computer2.

because bookmark is on cloud, there is no bookmarks or bookmarks.bak on local storage.

how can I get all lost bookmarks back.

Comment: In the hope that your bookmarks were also stored locally, look for the Bookmarks file - see [link](https://www.alphr.com/where-are-google-chrome-bookmarks-stored/). Search for it in your backups and in the Recycle Bin.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no local files because I always open the sync. but on google settings, I find there are a lot of bookmarks, but I cannot see it on my chrome.

Comment: If you see them, you can probably export them to a file, then import the bookmarks into Chrome and sync.